# WebSocket - кто закрыл соединение?

Tags: node.js, websocket

Использую модуль `ws`. Есть простой сервер:

```
const webSocket = require("ws");
const wsPort = 3333;
const online = {};
const wsServer = new webSocket.Server({
    port: wsPort
}, ()=>{
    console.log("**************Сервер Websocket слушает на порту:", wsPort, "**************")
});
wsServer.on("connection", (ws, req)=>{
    const id = Math.random();
    online[id] = ws;


    ws.on('close', function(code) {
        console.log(code) // 1001

  });
 });
```

Как узнать какой пользователь закрыл соединение?

Другими словами: я хочу узнать, какой пользователь генерирует событие `close`

Comment: В официальной документации [есть пример](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-client) для получения ip адреса клиента. А вот какой пользователь, из вопроса не понятно, дополните.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, это при подключении, когда срабатывает событие `connection`, а меня интересует момент, когда срабатывает событие `close`

Comment: Вообще-то так же само, в методе `'close'` используйте `req` , либо объявленный `id` , если это пользователь. Можете в консоль вывести при закрытии соединения для проверки.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, можете привести пример? Я пробовал - добавлял несколько параметров.. кроме кода закрытия, никакой информации больше получить не смог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно хранить ИД пользователя или другой идентификатор в функции, которая создает соединение и соответственно знать кто именно закрыл соединение. Исправленный код:

```
const webSocket = require("ws");
const wsPort = 3333;

var count = 0;
const online = {};
const wsServer = new webSocket.Server({
    port: wsPort
}, ()=>{
    console.log("**************Сервер Websocket слушает на порту:", wsPort, "**************")
});
wsServer.on("connection", (ws, req)=>{

    const userId = count++;
    console.log('user connect: ' + userId);
    online[userId] = ws;    

    ws.on('close', function(code) {
        console.log('user disconnect: ' + userId)
        delete online[userId];    
    });
});
```

Соответственно в `online` хранятся все подключенные пользователи, где ключом выступает id пользователя, а значением его connection `ws` .

Comment: вот я болван, "смотрю в книгу - вижу фигу")....благодарю)